# How to display will_paginate in the same line in Rails? and How to Style will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

1) I am trying to get the Paginate to display in same line instead of new line.  Currently I have

<< Previous
1
2
Next >>

My CSS is defined as follows:

```
.pagination{CSS Style code}
.pagination a {CSS Style code}
.pagination a.current{CSS Style code}
```

2) How to turn off << Previous and Next >>?

3) What is the a.(class) called for currently selected paginate?

Currently I have `.pagination a.current{CSS Style}` but it does not work

I am using https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

I am a complete Newbie in Rails; 
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/will_paginate/

Comment: I have tried digg, apple and flickr but still the same issues I am having (paginate still displays in the next line and current paginate still looks like every paginate buttons).

Answer (score 0):

In case, any body still needs help with this... because there are many things with the class `.pagination` all as part of the `<%=will_paginate %>`. You may want to refer to the parent element.

```
div.pagination {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and any other styling you may want.

Also, ensure that the parent element to that div does allow it to be spread out..
in case it happens to be in an

or  which have a width of 10px and you have 3000pages or that kind of thing.
you may want to remove it from it's parent element.